# How to prevent sc2gears from loading all replays every time it opens

Tags: starcraft-2, mods

[sc2gears](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/) is such a nice tool (despite some unavoidable inaccuracies), but there is one thing that bothers me. When I open the app, and I want to look at my latest few replays, I double-click on "SC2 auto reps" to load my replays. This takes a long time though as I have a lot of replays.

I would expect that by now, with so many features, sc2gears would cache old replays instead of parsing them again every time I run the app.

Is there a way to cache old replays? Or is there a way to "load last 50 replays" similar to the "load last replay" button?

Answer (score 4):

Sc2gears can cache replays, and this is enabled by default.
If you add the MD5 of the replays to the replay name, Sc2gears can open the replay list or the multi-replay analysis INSTANTLY (even with thousands of replays). To do this, you have to rename them, and include the /h symbol in the replay name.

You can also move your old replays to a separate folder, and leave the last 50 in the default folder where SC2 auto-saves them, that way double clicking on the "SC2 auto reps" will only open your last replays. You can create a replay source which points to the folder where you keep all your replays, and you could still open all your replays with double clicking on this new replay source.